# Elections inbox item is empty in network profile global inbox

Tags: bug, election, global-inbox, stackexchange.com

I got an inbox message about the elections on Super User yesterday, all good.

However, when checking now my global inbox on stackexchange.com network profile, it's empty:

> [image]

The inbox item on the top bar is fine:

> [image]

The empty item also got no link to the elections. Can this please be fixed?