# Self closing as duplicate

Tags: discussion

I'm just asking a question and soon be told to be (but not voted to close as) duplicate, and I self clicked to "close as duplicate", and I need to:

1. Vote the duplicate
2. Refresh the page
3. Agree on the duplicate vote

That's weird. Why is it designed so?

Comment: Why did you ask the question if you knew it was a duplicate? I.e. why go though steps 1 and 2?

Comment: @RobertLongson Find the duplicate after the asking

Comment: You're doing it wrong then. Search first.

Comment: @RobertLongson When a problem has billions of possible expression

Comment: @RobertLongson no. This happens, even to very long time users with lots of experience, e.g. myself: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292315/elections-inbox-item-is-empty-in-network-profile-global-inbox. So please don't blame the OP here, it's not very nice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've not blamed anyone, I've simply provided advice on the best course of action here. We recommend people [search first all the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), we even say on the downvote tooltip that "this question shows no research effort" is a reason to downvote. We should advise people to search, search and search again because that will get them the best possible experience here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's nothing "not nice" about saying don't do that, do this instead. My parents said that all the time when I was a child, I bet yours did too. How can we help people if we don't tell them to stop doing the wrong thing and start doing the right thing, or perhaps just do more of the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

It was never designed to work this way.

The expected flow of events is:

1. Someone posts a question.
2. After a while, someone else notice it's a duplicate, and cast a flag or close vote.
3. An automatic comment *Possible duplicate of ...* is generated. **This results in an inbox notification.**
4. The OP (original poster of the question) comes back to the question and notice the banner telling them about the duplicate and decide whether it's helpful or not.

That is how it was designed to work. The fact OP can also cast a flag/close vote and thus close their own question as duplicate all by themselves is just kind of "bonus", as I see it. Hence, I don't find the current system weird or flawed in any way.

Comment: This post caused this feature to be implemented: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930

Comment: oh sorry there must have been some edit conflict. I didn't intended removed your last line. I think it is still important to mention that there is an inbox notification due to the auto comment, but I don't think it is worth to write an full answer for this.

Comment: @MEE yeah, I added that sentence during grace period, you probably started to edit before I added it. Add the item again and I'll approve it. As for the feature request you're correct, but it doesn't clearly explain how the implemented banner is supposed to work so I didn't mention it in the answer.

Comment: yeah I know that the post linked in my comment is not really important but rather useful information (that is why I posted it as a comment).